# Is there something different about using AWS CLI commands in Bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, quotes, amazon-vpc

I am trying to write a script to tag AWS VPCs.

I have tested it using the AWS CLI command, and I am able to pass multiple VPCs as an argument and it works.

But when I do the same in my script, I get this :

> An error occurred (InvalidID) when calling the CreateTags operation:
> The ID ' vpc-0e452e6bf5585eaeb vpc-0f4ead0bc0625f657' is not valid

This is the AWS CLI command which successfully works:

```
aws ec2 create-tags \                                                                                                     
 --resources  vpc-0f4ead0bc0625f657 vpc-0e452e6bf5585eaeb  \        
 --tags Key=lw:managed,Value=False \
        Key=lw:managed:puppet,Value=False \
        Key=lw:managed:monitoring,Value=False \
        Key=lw:managed:os,Value=False \
        Key=lw:managed:ssm,Value=False \
        Key=lw:managed:backups,Value=False
```

But the same command in my script throws the above-mentioned error.

```
#!/bin/bash

labelVPC () {
  aws ec2 create-tags \
  --resources "$vpcs" \
  --tags Key=lw:managed,Value=$managed \
         Key=lw:managed:puppet,Value=$puppet \
         Key=lw:managed:monitoring,Value=$monitored \
         Key=lw:managed:os,Value=$os \
         Key=lw:managed:ssm,Value=$ssm \
         Key=lw:managed:backups,Value=$backups
  exit
}

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
 echo "You supplied wrong arguments"
 echo "example : `basename $0 ` vpc1 vpc2 etc"
exit 1
fi

vpcs=$1
tagValues=$2
managed=$(printf "${tagValues}" | cut -d':' -f1)
puppet=$(printf "${tagValues}" | cut -d':' -f2)
monitored=$(printf "${tagValues}" | cut -d':' -f3)
os=$(printf "${tagValues}" | cut -d':' -f4)
ssm=$(printf "${tagValues}" | cut -d':' -f5)
backups=$(printf "${tagValues}" | cut -d':' -f6)

labelVPC
```

And this is how I run the script:

```
./vpc-tagging-v3.sh "vpc-0e452e6bf5585eaeb vpc-0f4ead0bc0625f657" True:False:True:True:True
```

Comment: I think you need one additional True/False at the end, for backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a single argument to `resources:

```
--resources "$vpcs"
```

remove the quotes

```
--resources $vpcs
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.